# Why doesn't `Box::into_raw` take `self` as parameter?

Tags: rust

This simple program:

```
fn main() {
    let b: Box<i32> = Box::new(1);
    b.into_raw();
}
```

Produces this inconvenient error when compiled with Rust 1.12.0:

```
error: no method named `into_raw` found for type `Box<i32>` in the current scope
 --> <anon>:3:7
  |
3 |     b.into_raw();
  |       ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: found the following associated functions; to be used as methods, functions must have a `self` parameter
  = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `Box<_>`
```

This is because `into_raw` is not defined to take `self` as parameter, but instead is defined as:

```
impl Box<T: ?Sized> {
    fn into_raw(b: Box<T>) -> *mut T;
}
```

This seems inconvenient, and I cannot find a rationale.

So... why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because 99.995% of the time (statistic totally made up), [you expect method calls to happen to the thing being pointed *to*, not to the pointer *itself*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/a068fc70ab38adea73f84a8f8c6f826454ce563b).  As a result, the "smart pointer" types in Rust *generally* avoid doing anything to break that expectation.  An obvious exception would be something like `Rc`/`Arc` implementing `Clone` directly.

Comment: Ah thanks! I was wracking my brain in totally the wrong direction and had not considered that most method calls are forwarded to the pointee via `Defer`.

Answer (score 8):

`Box` implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), which means that all methods that are enclosed by the `Box` are automatically made available; from the outside, `Box<T>` and `T` look and act the same.

If `into_raw` were a method instead of an associated function, it would shadow any `into_raw` method on the contained type.

There are other examples of these enhancing associated functions on [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html), such as `downgrade` or `try_unwrap`, or on [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), such as `make_mut`.

Comment: See [the pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21318) adding these functions to the standard library.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: An excellent source indeed, the comment by alexcrichton explains it exactly.